# Error en deploy en Railway

Tags: nodejs, permisos, deployment

Estoy intentando deployar un proyecto backend en Railway y me arroja este error:

```
npm WARN config production Use `--omit=dev` instead.

proyecto-backend@1.0.0 start

src/app.js

**sh: 1: src/app.js: Permission denied**
@deployment: 92081a4c-8d56-44b8-ad53-856c5bf03c47
@replica: 63f9e1da-cb6f-4a95-87ba-30aee31d1105
@service: df6f0bb5-ee4e-493b-9da2-8a0083e5fca2
```

según la interfaz grafica de windows me dice que el archivo app.js tiene permisos de:
control total, modificar, lectura y ejecucion, lectura, escritura.
tanto en system, usuario y administradores.